# Combine 3 WiFi routers into one network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have 3 WiFi routers. I want them to all work together to make one network all throughout the house.

Router A: Actiontec PK5000 (DSL modem/router combo)

Router B & C: TP-Link TL-WR841N

Ethernet switch: Netgear FS105

Router A is connected directly to the internet because it's also a modem.
One Ethernet cable goes from Router A to an Ethernet switch. From the switch, one Ethernet cable goes to Router B, and another goes to Router C.

Currently, I have them all set up with different SSIDs. I'd like them all to be one network with three different access points (I think that's the term?).

```
[Router A]-----------------[ethernet switch]
                              |          |
                        [Router B]   [Router C]
```

None of the WiFi networks have passwords because this is a really rural area and there is simply no need.

I want all 3 WiFi networks to work together to create one WiFi network with one SSID. If possible, I also want a printer connected to Router A to be able to be used by a device connected to any other routers.

I *think* that there's something about turning off DHCP on Router B and C and then... I'm not sure what exactly.

Also, the router control panel IPs are set to:
Router A: 192.168.0.1, Router B and C: 192.168.1.1

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, basically you need to turn off (or avoid) the "router" part, and use the devices as plain "bridges". Some actually have a mode for this, but for the rest, Linef4ult's advice is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you need to take are:

1. Make sure TP units are connected via LAN **not** WAN port.
2. Disable DHCP on both TP units
3. Assign the TPs static IPs within the range of the Actiontec, eg 192.168.0.250 and 192.168.0.251 (Currently they are conflicting)
4. Replicate the SSID across all 3, but use **different** channels (eg CH1, CH6, C11)

Devices will then all "see" each other and roam relatively smoothly.

Comment: With your directions, I got everything working, except I can't access the router control panels. That's not important to me though. I tried setting a static IP on a TP, then I tried just using the dynamic IP provided by the Actiontec's DHCP. Neither one worked. When everything was set up, I can see the IP of the routers on the Actiontec's control panel, but when I try to access them or ping them, I get nothing. And the shortcut domain, tplinklogin.net, is going to the Actiontec, which goes to the actual domain, rather than displaying a router's control panel.